# How do I write a MERGE statement with a special "NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE" condition?

Tags: sql-server, merge

- I am using SQL Server 2016
- I have a set of server names and attribute columns in my SOURCE staging table, which is populated by a scanner
- I need to merge this into my TARGET table, so that the TARGET and SOURCE are identical at the end of the merge's execution
- The catch is that sometimes the SOURCE does not have any data about certain servers (because the scanner failed to connect to that server) In such cases, I don't want to delete the rows in TARGET for that server

Here is what I have (but the item after the comment does not work) Note that I have removed the INSERT part because that part works and is not the issue:

`MERGE TargetTable AS TARGET
USING SourceTable AS SOURCE
ON SOURCE.[ServerName] = TARGET.[ServerName]
AND SOURCE.[Version]   = TARGET.[Version]
WHEN MATCHED AND 
   SOURCE.[Platform]  <> TARGET.[Platform]
THEN UPDATE SET
   TARGET.[Platform] = SOURCE.[Platform]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT...
-- The following is the part that does not work
-- What I am trying to do below is first check whether the ServerName in 
-- TARGET is present in SOURCE (i.e. scanner succeeded in reading from that 
-- server. Only in that case, do I delete the row
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND TARGET.[ServerName] IN (SELECT [ServerName] FROM SOURCE) 
THEN DELETE
;`

Here is an example. Let's say that the following are the start states of SOURCE and TARGET:

```
SOURCE
ServerName      Version      Platform
----------------------------------------
Server1           1.0         Win2012
Server2           2.0         Win2016
Server4           4.0         Win2016


TARGET
ServerName        Version   Platform
-------------------------------------
Server1           1.0         Win2012
Server2           2.0         Win2012
Server3           3.0         Win2016
Server4           5.0         Win2016
```

Here is the expected result in target after the merge

```
ServerName      Version     Platform
-------------------------------------
Server1           1.0         Win2012
Server2           2.0         Win2016
Server3           3.0         Win2016
Server4           4.0         Win2016
```

## Logic

- Server1 is unchanged between SOURCE and TARGET; retain as is in TARGET
- Server2's Platform (same version in SOURCE and TARGET) got updated in SOURCE; so update its attributes in TARGET
- Server3 is NOT present in SOURCE anymore (could be because of scanner error); so don't delete from TARGET
- Server4 has a new version in SOURCE; so the Server was indeed scanned. Add the SOURCE row to TARGET but delete the missing row from TARGET

Comment: How would it not be matched by source, yet the servername would still be in source? You're merging on the server name :/ Sample data and expected results would help to get an understanding of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks! I have added the example to the original quesiton

Comment: @syzygy78, Well, it looks like you simply don't need `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE` clause at all. This part is optional in the `MERGE` statement. You are never deleting from `Target`. Or are you? Expand your sample data and show a clear example when you do want to delete from `Target`.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir --- I have captured a distilled example of what I am looking for. Sorry, previously I had lost fidelity when I was trying to come up with a simplified example

Comment: Based on the sample rows, and on most of your explanation, there is no reason to have any `DELETE` operations, only `INSERT` and `UPDATE` (when matched). Can you explain more consistently in which cases when you want to delete from the target? Perhaps you're getting mixed up with an `UPDATE` here. Personally, I avoid `MERGE` and use seperate statements unless unless I have a good reason.

Comment: It seems to me that the final point in your logic explanation is redundant if you consider just the `server` as the key and the `version` as an attribute. Do you ever want to store different combinations of server and version as different rows? if not, then it would appear that `server` is your unique key

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid --- It is possible to have different versions for same computer. In other words, PK is (servername + version) 

An example of a scenario when I wish to do a delete from TARGET for a given server S1, is the following:

- SOURCE has at least one row with S1 in it (indicating that the scanner successfully scanned S1)
- Let's say SOURCE and TARGET have the following to begin with:
SOURCE : (S1, V1, P1)

TARGET: (S1, V1, P1), (S1, V1, P2) 

We want to delete (S1, V1, P2) from the TARGET, since it is no longer in the SOURCE.

Comment: So you can actually have two records in target with the same server and version in them? I think that would cause an error in your merge statement. Apologies for all the questions but I don't quite understand the primary key in this situation. If your logic requires things to happen in a certain order then I suggest you break it up into multiple insert/update/delete statements. In fact I suggest you do that regardless! Can you edit and add the above case? (where there is a duplicate server/version in target). I suspect there may be some ambiguity about how records are merged in

Comment: @syzygy78, please, edit the question and extend the sample data. Make sure to include all possible cases.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your feedback. I am upvoting Nick's suggestion to not use MERGE and instead use INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE, since that has already gotten me past most of my challenges. I think this scenario is just too complicated to be handled within a single MERGE :(